# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' ...)

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm using Android Studio 2.1 and trying to use a full screen theme without action bar.

I changed this in my manifest, as stated in [Using platform styles and themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

```
-        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
+        android:theme="@android:style/Material.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
```

However when compiling the app I now get this error message:

```
Error:(19, 24) No resource found that matches the given name
(at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Material.NoActionBar.FullScreen').
```

This makes me think I have to somehow include these styles in the resources of my project. But according to the documentation, it should just be a matter of changing the name of the theme, and because the prefix `@android` it would be a standard theme which is already in the platform.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: try to change to `@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar.Fullscreen`

Comment: When I do that and click `Run App`, Android Studio changes it back to the original value.

Comment: Are you sure you're editing original manifest, not one generated under `/build` folder?

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You style reference lacks `Theme.` in path. Proper full name is

```
@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar.Fullscreen
```

Also be aware that Android Studio offers code completion also in styles, so you can enter i.e. `@android:style/Theme.Ma` or `@android:style/fulls` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to see all available matching styles.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar.Fullscreen
```

your target api, add this also

```
tools:targetApi="lollipop"
```

> **Theme.Material.NoActionBar.Fullscreen reuires API 21**